# Unable to set negative margin in jQuery css method

Tags: jquery, width, margin

may I ask you? How do I set negative margin (or anything else) in .css() method in jQuery? I am adding the size by variable, but it doesn´t works

```
var width = $('.gallery div img').outerWidth(true);
$('.gallery').css('margin-left', '- ' + width + 'px');
```

Or is there any way how to convert `var width` into negative number?

Comment: You have a space between the negative and the value. You have "- 50px", not "-50px".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me on this StackOverflow page:

`$(".bottom-notice").css("margin-left", "-"+500+"px");`

Notice there's no space between the - and the closing ". I think that might be what is causing your issue. Otherwise make sure `width` is actually a number.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

Check width first to make sure its a number, and then take the space out and the true.

```
var mywidth = $('.gallery div img').outerWidth();
alert(mywidth);
$('.gallery').css('margin-left', '-' + mywidth + 'px');
```